# Целочисленное деление отрицательных целых чисел

Tags: python

Вопрос возник при решении задачи о палиндроме.
Вот решение

```
def palindrom(param):
    #  convert to str
    word = str(param)
    #   in cycle char by char comparing from start and from end to middle of the word
    return True if word[:len(word)//2] == word[:-len(word)//2-1:-1] else False

if palindrom(input("give me a word: ")):
    print("Палиндром")
else:
    print("Та ну не")
```

которое работает для слов четной длины, и не работает для слов с нечтным количеством символов.
Оказалось, что `7//2==3`,  а `-7//2==-4`
то есть задачу то я решил:

```
return  word[:len(word)//2] == word[:-(len(word)//2)-1:-1]
```

но почему так реализовано целочисленное деление?
Хотелось бы `-7//2 ==-3`.
Какой тут глубинный смысл? А то ведь

```
7//2  + (- 7//2)  == -1 
7//2 - 7//2  ==  0
```

P.S.:     признателен gil9red за подсказки и краткое решение задачи о палиндроме в примечаниях ниже.
P.P.S.:   что интересно, операции побитового двоичного сдвига тоже соблюдают данное правило:

```
 7>>1 == 3
-7>>1 == -4
```

Comment: Оффтоп, а в чем смысл использовать конструкцию `True if ... == ... else False`, если результатом `... == ...` и так будет True / False? :) Кст, а как вам такой алгоритм проверки на палиндром `return param == param[::-1]`?

Comment: @gil9red ну да, я тупонул, правда ты тоже - вопрос про другое

Comment: @gil9red.
 Ничего что я на "ты"? Да твое решение блестяще, для коротких строк будет работать быстрее приведенного мной. Благодарю.
Правда для чисел работать не будет.
Поэтому точнее `word ==word[::-1]`

Comment: Я не против, а как у вас числа попали в функцию? У вас ведь в нее значения через `input` попадают, а тот только `str` возвращает: `palindrom(input("give me a word: "))`, впрочем, это нормальная практика предусмотреть разные типы аргументов в своих функциях

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Дело в том, как определяется целочисленное деление.

**Определение**

> Разделить целое число a на целое число b!=0 с остатком — это значит
>
> найти такие два целых q и r, которые удовлетворяют следующим условиям:
>
> 1) a = b * q + r;
>
> 2) 0 <= r < |b|.

Тогда из определения будет:

```
-7 // 2 = -4
```

Объяснение:

1. При делении отрицательного числа на положительное, получится отрицательное число
2. Можно предположить, что правильный ответ `-3`, но в этом случае умножив `-3 * 2` мы получим `-6`. Чтобы получить исходное `-7` нужно к результату прибавить число `-1`, но остаток не может быть отрицательным по определению(r>=0). По этому в данном случае остаток равен `1` и частное равно `-4`.

Comment: Отличное пояснение!

Comment: Если остаток не может быть отрицательным, почему 7 % -2 = -1

Comment: @ДмитрийСмирнов потому что "целочисленное деление" != "взятие остатка", а вопрос именно о целочисленном делении. А то, что вы спрашиваете, это не  просто остаток от деления. Он называется  оператор `modulo` и всегда принимает знак делителя. Подробнее в [доке](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) И вот еще немножко на [habr'e](https://habr.com/ru/post/421071/)

Answer (score 1):

Вот что у меня получилось.
Как оказалось законы математики и формула в Python по вычислению остатка разные.
Общая формула a%b=r (a=b*q+r), где q неполное частное, r остаток.
Для математики, в которой по правилам остаток не может быть отрицательным:

```
-19%5=1 (-19=5*(-4)+1)
19%-5=4 (-21=5*(-5)+4)
-19%-5=1 (-19=(-5)*4+1)
-5%19=14 (-5=19*(-1)+14)
5%-19=5 (5=(-19)*0+5)
-5%-19=14 (-5=(-19)*1+14)
```

Для Python, где остаток может быть отрицательным:

```
-19%5=1 (-19=5*(-4)+1) сходится
19%-5=-1 (19=(-5)*(-4)-1) не сходится
-19%-5=-4  (-19=(-5)*3-4) не сходится
-5%19=14  (-5=19*(-1)+14) сходится
5%-19=-14  (5=(-19)*(-1)-14) не сходится
-5%-19=-5  (-5=(-19)*0-5) не сходится
```

Итого: неполное частное "q" округляется в меньшую целую сторону, так же как и с делением нацело. Т.е. если у вас одно число помещается в другом -3,XX раза, берется -4, если 3,XX раза, берется 3, если 0,xx раз, берется 0. Моя логика так нарисовала)

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, как ваше соообщение отвечает на вопрос заданный в этой теме. Ранее данный ответ я понимаю, но ваш ответ пока не совсем.

Comment: Вы поторопились. Все сходится, просто надо читать [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html).